# Can I override the Json.Net member-name mapping, within the context of a single serializer?

Tags: c#, .net, couchdb, json.net

I'm trying to write documents into CouchDB in .NET, but my I don't want to mark all of my `Id` properties with `[JsonProperty(MemberName = "_id")]`, since I need to serialize them normally (with the member name being `Id`) to send them out via my own HTTP API.

Basically, I want this:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
/* some magic happens */
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, new Thing { Id = "foo", Value = "bar" });
```

To result in this:

```
{_id:"Foo",Value:"Bar"}
```

But without the magic joojoo, it should still be this:

```
{Id:"Foo",Value:"Bar"}
```

I'm assuming that this shouldn't be too hard, but I don't know my way around the internals of Json.Net well enough to Just Do It™.

Comment: Which version of JSON.net are you using? Because my (newest) version doesn`t have a SerializeObject method (but Serialize) on a JsonSerializer and you have to call it with a TextWriter instead of returning the value?

Comment: @Marc: yeah, I hadn't actually tried to compile that code.  I have fixed it.

Comment: I suspect you meant to use the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method.

Comment: @Jeff: I did not.  I meant to use `JsonSerializer.Serialize`, since I can customize that particular instance of the serializer.

Comment: FWIW, all the settings you can change in your serializer can be set using a `JsonSerializerSettings` object. The `JsonConvert` methods accepts these settings. So you can effectively customize the settings object and not keep around the serializer instance. Plus you don't have to deal with having to manage a separate text writer if you just want to serialize an object to a JSON string.

Comment: @Jeff: Fair point.  In my specific case, I'm serializing to and from HTTP streams (CouchDB) so I actually prefer the text writer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a ContractResolver:

```
public class IdContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "Id") return "_id";
        return base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Then add the magic by attaching it:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.ContractResolver = new IdContractResolver();
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, new Thing { Id = "foo", Value = "bar" });
```

And you get:

```
{_id:"Foo",Value:"Bar"}
```

Comment: That was easy.  I was not aware of the concept of ContractResolvers.